# Ruby precompiled libraries

Tags: ruby, libraries

For example I installed devise gem in my ruby project and I can see all it's source code. Is it possible to have a library without source code in a form of precompiled binary? Like assembly in .Net? And how to add it to the project without gem package manager, manually?

Comment: What's your use case for wanting precompile libraries?

Comment: Any form of compiled Ruby is fundamentally incompatible with every bit of Ruby infrastructure out there.

Comment: @tadman Would you expand on why?

Comment: @pjs Pretty much every Ruby implementation expects plain Ruby source. The notable exception to this is jRuby which can [compile to JVM bytecode](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/2/15/is-ruby-interpreted-or-compiled) that's useful only within a JVM environment.

Comment: @tadman Yes, but if somebody came up with an implementation that could save or load the MRI/YARV byte code, it would work with all the gems and other sources out there.  The incompatibility would be one-way.  When I saw the phrase "fundamentally incompatible" I thought you meant that such an implementation couldn't work with pre-existing code from elsewhere.  In fact, it would be very much like jRuby, which I don't think of as "fundamentally incompatible" with gems or outside source.

Comment: @pjs The internal bytecode was not designed to be persisted or shared in any capacity. I'm also talking about the situation today, not some hypothetical future which doesn't exist. jRuby is not 100% compatible with MRI, so it's not an option for everyone. I just use it as an example here as one way this might be managed using existing tools. The straight answer is, today, given today's tools, this isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in Ruby. The closest you'll come to in Ruby is extensions that wrap precompiled libraries. For example [Nokogiri](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri) or [bcrypt-ruby](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Ruby is not a compiled language. Although YARV compiles the source code on the fly, it does not generate byte code. The only compiled implementation of Ruby, Rubinius, does not promise byte code compatibility among different versions (even among minor versions).

Comment: Technically it's compiled to bytecode in MRI/YARV, but that bytecode is not  normally emitted anywhere. It's not expected to be useful outside of the scope of the process that generated it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "compiled language". Compilation is a trait of the compiler, not the language. All language can be compiled. Also, Rubinius is not the "only compiled implementation". In fact, in there was only one implementation of Ruby that didn't have a compiler (MRI), and that implementation is obsolete, deprecated and unmaintained. All currently existing implementations (YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, Topaz, Opal, Cardinal, MacRuby, MRuby, RubyMotion, etc.) have compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does not have a portable format for code other than the Ruby Language itself. The only other portable format it has, is the `Marshal` format, but that is only for data, it cannot serialize code, i.e. all methods, `Proc`s, lambdas, and blocks will be left out and/or cause an error.

Note that this is actually no different from other languages. E.g. the Java Language and the JVM bytecode language are two distinct languages defined in two distinct specifications. There is no guarantee that an implementation of Java also includes an implementation of JVML and vice versa. For example, Avian only implements the JVML, it does not implement Java. And GWT only implements Java, but not the JVML.

For example, Java applications that rely on being able to execute JVM bytecode on the fly (e.g. JRuby with its JIT compiler or the Kilim concurrency framework) won't work on Android. JRuby solves this by disabling the JIT on Android and running purely interpreted.

JRuby and IronRuby both have Ahead-Of-Time compilers that compile Ruby to JVML bytecode and CLI CIL bytecode, respectively. Opal has an Ahead-Of-Time compiler that compiles Ruby to ECMAScript.

YARV has an Ahead-Of-Time compiler that compiles Ruby to YARV bytecode, however, that bytecode is usually fed directly to the YARV bytecode VM and never persisted or exposed anywhere. And there is a good reason for that: YARV bytecode is unsafe, the YARV VM implicitly trusts that the compiler will only generate code which doesn't corrupt the VM. That's a reasonable assumption to make if the compiler is part of the VM, but if you allow bytecode to be read in from external sources, then you don't know what compiler produced it, and you can get the VM in an inconsistent state.

In order to prevent this, either the bytecode has to be changed to be safe, or the VM needs a bytecode verifier.

You *can* actually access the bytecode, and, with some work, it is possible to read it from a file and execute, but for the reasons I outlined, that is unsafe.

Rubinius supports writing and reading bytecode to and from files, but that is not really intended for distributing bytecode archives. Rubinius uses it for caching the compiled bytecode as a latency optimization (similar to how CPython does). There used to be a feature in Rubinius similar to JVM `.class` and `.jar` files (`.rbc` and `.rba`), where you could load code from an `.rba` archive, but I'm not sure it still exists.

So, several Ruby implementations have several degrees of support of some form of bytecode compilation, but none that work robustly, and none that are portable across Ruby implementations.